# C2276 or C3867 compiler errors in C++

Tags: c++, class, compiler-errors

I need to send a class member function 'curve' to another function 'fun', but I get errors during compilation. How to code this correctly?

Using address '&' results in C2276, without using it - C3867.

```cpp
class Test
{
public:
    double v;

    double curve(double x)
    {
        return x + v;
    }

    Test(double z)
    {
        v = z;
    }
};

double fun(double(*f)(double), double x)
{
    return f(x);
}

void main()
{
    Test d(2.0);

    double r = fun(&d.curve, 3.0);
}
```

Comment: You *probably* need to use `std::bind` or, better yet, a lambda that just calls the function.

Comment: Okay, I tried ```auto f = [&](double x) {return d.curve(x); }; double r = fun(f, 3.0);``` but this results in C2664

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can change the `fun` signature, the answer of **rafix07** is perfect.

If you don't want to change the number of parameters of `fun`, you probably want to write something like that:

```
double fun(double(*f)(double), double x)
{
    return f(x);
}

int main() // not void
{
    Test d(2.0);
    double r = fun([d](double double_){ return d.curve(double_); }, 3.0);
    std::cout << r;
}
```

Sadly **it doesn't work** because a lambda can be stored in a function pointer only if it doesn't use a capture.

So you have 2 solutions:

**1) the template**

```
// Must be in .hpp
template <class T>
double fun(T f, double x)
{
    return f(x);
}

int main() // not void
{
    Test d(2.0);
    double r = fun([d](double double_) mutable { return d.curve(double_); }, 3.0);
}
```

**2) the std::function**

```
#include <functional>
double fun(std::function<double(double)> f, double x)
{
    return f(x);
}
```

**Note:** you have to use `mutable` because `double curve(double x)` is not `const`, I think it should be.

Comment: Okay, the 2nd solution works perfectly when I work with CLR console application. Once I tried this line in my main CLR project, I got C3923 error ('member' : local class, struct, or union definitions are not allowed in a member function of a managed class). The function looks like
```Matrix integrate(std::function<double(double)> f, unsigned steps, unsigned substeps, double end, double start = 0.0) {...}``` 
and I call it like
```Input d;
Matrix r = integrate([d](double double_) mutable { return d.curvature(double_); }, 100, 10, 3.1416 / 2.0);```

Comment: Well, you may try the solution of rafix07 because it's lambda free (lambda is anonymous class) . AFAIK it's look like a bug/limitation of visual studio. You should probably close this question (because the problem you describ is resolve) and open a new one with the `visual-studio` tag and all information you have

Answer (score 2):

`curve` is a member function of `Test` class so you need to have an instance of `Test` on which `curve` can be called.

You can change `fun` to take as first parameter pointer to member function and as second param pass a reference to `Test` instance, the result code may look like:

```
class Test {
public:
    double v;

    double curve(double x) {
        return x + v;
    }

    Test(double z) {
        v = z;
    }
};

double fun(  double(Test::*f)(double)  , Test& obj, double x) {
    return (obj.*f)(x);
}

int main()
{
    Test d(2.0);
    double r = fun(&Test::curve, d, 3.0);
}
```